# React native textDecoration properties not working on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using on

```
<Text style={styles.sampleStyle}> Something </Text>
```

the following styles:

```
sampleStyle: {
    textDecorationLine: "underline",
    textDecorationStyle: "solid",
    textDecorationColor: "#000",
}
```

However, they don't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like this is only supported for IOS currently: `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#content` Did you find another solution or library to solve this?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. Since I only needed it on one line of text I faked the underline with a view underneath it.

Answer (score 50):

You didn't specify the style you want for your Text component. Try with :

```
<Text style={styles.sampleStyle} >Something </Text>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sampleStyle: {
    textDecorationLine: "underline",
    textDecorationStyle: "solid",
    textDecorationColor: "#000"
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't directly copy the code, I was just trying to demonstrate what I was trying to achieve. All the other styles are working, but not the decoration.

Comment: textDecorationStyle: "dotted" not working with android

Comment: textDecorationColor: "#000" This is not working on my side

Comment: Alternative is to use `borderBottomColor` and `borderBottomWidth`, for me it's not working at all with this environment : react: 18.1.0, react-native: 0.70.5, android API 33.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Text style={styles.sampleStyle}>Something</Text>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    sampleStyle: {
        color: "#000"
    }
});
```

An old question, but here's a quick answer for those still searching in 2020+

For Android it seems that simply using color: is what is needed. If you take a look at the docs, textDecorationColor is labeled for ios use.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props

Comment: what if I want text to be in black color and strikethrough in red, how to achieve this in android.(it works in iOS)

Answer (score 0):

```
sampleStyle: {
   textDecorationLine: "underline",
   textDecorationStyle: "solid",
   textDecorationColor: "#000",
}
```

only works on ios